# How to mock json file data in jasmine

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I have players.json data, I want to mock all data of that file using jasmine. How to access angularjs modules data in jasmine.

Comment: something like [karma-fixture](https://github.com/billtrik/karma-fixture) ?

Comment: Can you provide sample code of what you are trying to test. It is easier to provide you with an example in code that you wrote.